# Add insecure rubygems source and automatically choose 'yes' for 'Do you want to add this insecure source?' (I'm using Docker-Compose)

Tags: docker, rubygems, docker-compose

I am provisioning an install of a node that uses some ruby gems. In order to get the gems on my corporate network I usually add 'http://rubygems.org'.

I am using Docker compose and wand to use

`gem source --add http://rubygems.org`, but I noticed it asks me interactively `[yn]`.

How can I avoid the interaction, similar to `apt-get install -yqq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the gem source in `~/.gemrc` file, without the interaction with the `gem source` command.

```
$> echo -e '--- \nsources:\n- http://rubygems.org/' >> ~/.gemrc
```

That command will generate next file:

```
--- 
sources:
- http://rubygems.org/
```

Which will be used by `rubygems` package.

<sub>[Rubygems documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/)</sub>